# Compare 3 columns of a 2-D List and Replace based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 2-D List as follows:

```
 [
 [6 4 4 2   5 5 4 5     4 1 3 5]
 [4 3 6 5   4 4 5 1     5 5 2 4]
 [2 5 2 0   4 5 4 4     2 3 2 6]
 [5 5 4 3   5 4 6 7     3 4 4 4]
 [3 5 6 5   6 5 3 5     3 4 7 4]
 [4 5 5 4   5 4 7 5     3 5 4 1]
 [2 5 3 3   5 3 4 4     3 3 1 3]
 [2 5 5 2   5 4 6 2     5 6 2 5]
]
```

Conditions:
compare column 1,5 and 9 (in steps of 4) - row-wise and process them in the following order

1. If one of them is zero - do nothing. Go to Step 2
   (6,5,4) - none of them zero so go to step 2
2. If they are all equal - change all of them to zero. If not go Step 3
3. Take the lowest of the three and subtract each by this minimum
   Repeat this with next three elements (2,6,10) until (4,8,12)

How to do efficiently this in python using pandas or numpy or even list operation.
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom function and then apply that functions to every element in the array.

```
def check_conditions(x):
    for i in range(4):
        if x[i] == 0 or x[i+4] == 0 or x[i+8] == 0:
            continue
        elif x[i] == x[i+4] == x[i+8]:
            x[i] = 0
            x[i+4] = 0
            x[i+8] = 0
        else:
            min_val = min(x[i], x[i+4], x[i+8])
            x[i] -= min_val
            x[i+4] -= min_val
            x[i+8] -= min_val
    return x

new_arr = [check_conditions(x) for x in arr]
```

To get the following result.

```
print(new_arr)

[[2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5],
 [0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4],
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6],    
 [2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2, 3, 2, 0, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am doing. But I was wondering whether there is any "pythonic" "few-liner" like using np.where or pandas.
Something like
`
if (df[i]== df[i+4]==0 & df[i] ==df[i+8]:
    df[i] = 0
    df[i+4] = 0
    df[i+8]=0
`